# How do I access Cognito user's password verifier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I assume Cognito uses [SRP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2945#section-3) protocol and it stores user credentials as triplets  -
{ <username>, <password verifier>, <salt> }

As Admin, how do I access password verifier?

Comment: What do you mean by "access password verifier"?

Comment: I was curious if I could retrieve/read it for all users in case if I want to migrate all users out of Cognito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. There is no way to get passwords out of Cognito. There are tools to get everything but the passwords out of Cognito if you wanted to migrate out of it, but you would have to make all users choose new passwords afterwards